# Using SublimeText2 as MySql query editor

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2

Following [these](http://bartinger.at/execute-mysql-from-sublime-text-2/) [two](http://seant23.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/sublime-text-2-execute-mysql-query/) links and [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPd4m3PLVqU), i tried to make SublimeText 2 as the editor for MySql . However , i can't seem to get it to work. Build happens , but i dont get any output on the file i selected. Nor do i get any output on any command shell/console.

My build file :

```
{
    "cmd": ["mysql", "-u", "root", "-p" , "password_here_", 
            "-o", "F:/code/mysql/mysql-data/myHfs/output.txt", "-e", "source $file"],
    "working_dir": "F:/code/mysql" 
    "selector": "source.sql"
}
```

---

**Screenshots:**

---

- What i'm doing on the whole :
  [image]

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution for this problem? If yes, please post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is necessary to have that many parameters in the build file. This is my build file and am able to execute the .sql file using Ctrl+B. (I am on Windows btw)

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql", "-uroot", "-pMyPassword", "-e", "source $file", "-v", "-t"],
"selector": "source.sql"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are mistakenly using -o.
The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html) say:

> --one-database, -o
>
> Ignore statements except those that occur while the default database
>   is the one named on the command line. This option is rudimentary and
>   should be used with care. Statement filtering is based only on USE
>   statements.

I think you are trying to write the output to a file but I don't know that you can do it using the "cmd" portion of the build file. Normally, with a CLI you would redirect the output using >. That doesn't work here. I also tried using the tee option but apparently tee only works in interactive mode.

One option is to select your queries into an outfile in the source file but that's not very global:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/whatever.txt' FROM player;
```

Comment: Doing this manually on the cmd : `mysql -uroot -p < F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql -t` , i get what i want. i just have to figure this out with sublimetext